# Best Method to Vectorize Logo

Tags: vector

I'm a pretty decent graphic designer but I'm not quite sure 
what the best method would be to make it a vector image.

I'm going to try and make it with the pen tool and gradient fills.

This was is an edited logo from a stock logo site and is only a large png.
I've tried using various live tracing methods but they don't seem to work.

Any ideas you can come up with help me thanks!

[image]

Comment: What software do you want to use? What have you tried? What research have you looked at? What has gone wrong? Showing effort will get you better answers. As it is your question may be closed because of its poor quality

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip I will add more detail too the question. I got this as a jpeg and edited it in photoshop but it has to many problems so I wanted to make it a vector.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is rather subjective.

For me, it's always easiest to work with....

1. shapes -- draw standard circles, ellipses, rectangles, triangles,
   etc to fit portions where appropriate
2. Pathfinder/Shape Builder -- use these tools to reduce the shapes to
   the necessary elements.
3. Pen tool -- draw areas which can not be achieved via standard
   shapes.
4. Pathfinder/Shape Builder again -- use these tools to reduce the
   drawn areas with existing areas to the necessary elements.
5. Refine - use any number of methods to better smooth curves or refine
   shapes.
6. Color - add colors where needed using gradients, solids or meshes
   where required.

In the end almost all the vector conversions I do come down to these 6 steps in varying degrees. There are times where merely 1, 2, and 6 are needed. And others where 3 - 6 are all that's used. In your particular sample I'd use all 6 - start with circles, add pen drawn paths, refine, then color.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd doit (considering that the logo itself could have been executed much better):
1. Make a square with rounded corners that fits the bottom of the cloud (so that the edges look like 2 circles.
2. Add the top circle and make sure it's diameter fits the round corners of he square.
3. Unite everything using the pathfinder window.
4.Give it a big stroke and then turn it into a shape by goinf to object>path>outline stroke (at this stage I would copy and paste a version of the "stroked" one, it could come in handy if you make a mistake.
5. Using the direct selection tool (white arrow) fix the edges (that are diagonal)
6. Using a circle  in different sizes and placing it in different positions, start to "cut out" the different inner shapes by using the divide tool from the pathfinder window.
7. Start making your gradients. Notice that some parts have a gradient fill and also a gradient stroke.